# Array formula is not working to my subsequent entries - filling rest of the entries with respect to the first entry only

Tags: arrays, array-formulas

Im using an array formula in google sheet as a response to a google form which has an F field that has the first name of a person (say, thomas) and a G field whic is the last name of a person(say, mathew)and E field that has a custom email domain say "test.org" - the result expected is "thomasm_@test.org"
Im applying this array formula to one of my header field which will be given with a header name "UserID".

```
    ArrayFormula(IFS(ROW(A:A)=1, "UserID", LEN(A:A)=0, IFERROR(1/0), LEN(A:A)>0,LOWER(CONCATENATE(SUBSTITUTE(F2," ",""),LEFT(G2,1),"_",E2))))
```

Applying this formula it will apply to whatever entries i had given in the second row to all subsequent rows.. subsequent entries are not reflecting... Pls help

Answer (score 0):

Hi @richtom welcome to this community!
A few reasons:
`concatenate` function will not work inside of an `arrayfunction` as you're expecting, so avoid this.
Another thing is that also here `SUBSTITUTE(F2," ",""),LEFT(G2,1),"_",E2)`, you must use the same rangesize as in the beginning, i.e. A:A... F:F... G:G. the use of F2 will use F2 only in all rows.

So, I recommend the following:

```
=arrayformula(if(row(F:F)=row(),"UserID",if(F:F="","",if(G:G="","",if(E:E="","",lower(substitute(F:F & left(G:G,1) & "_@" & E:E," ","")))))))
```